# Using Adafruit with Google Assistant actions

Tags: google-assistant

I have a IoT device with WiFi connectivity. I am trying to implement the Google Assistant on my device, which works so far. I am using  IFTTT and Adafruit to connect my device with Google Assistant.

In Adafruit, I want to create feeds, and through this feed is all the data received by the IoT device. When I make thousands of the IoT device and give them to users, is it necessary to create multiple feeds in Adafruit or is there any other way?

When building Actions on Google is it possible to control thousands of devices?

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to make a product then I am sorry to say that IFTTT and Adafruit can't be used for production level.

And if you want to do so then you have to create your own device IFTTT compatible so your users can download IFTTT and link it by their own.

**For IFTTT Option :**
[https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/soumyadeeppal/ifttt-dialogflow-webhook](http://To%20Host%20your%20own%20server%20and%20make%20your%20device%20connected%20with%20it.%20check%20this%20out)

And one thing to notice here is that using IFTTT makes it very slower and it is not a native option for google assistant. Native Google Assistant Home Control can be done by Actions on Google Platform.

**If you want to learn from basic how to make one:**

[https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer/#0](http://Smart%20Home%20Washer%20-%20Codelab)

Comment: Is it needed to create multiple Heroku account while using multiple device?

Comment: No if you use google Native Google Assistant Home Control then you can implement oath so only 1 server will be required to handle all the devices.

Comment: could you please tell ,why ifttt is slower?

Comment: First of all IFTTT servers are shared servers not private server like heroku or aws which only handles your requests. 

Another point to consider is IFTTT adds a extra communication node in your network like first Google assistant sends a request to IFTTT then it processes it and send request to Adafruit and then to your device which makes it considerably slower.

Comment: implement oath so only 1 server will be required to handle all the devices.. could you please tell  me in detail(simply)                                                             oath link between  Heroku app or google assistance?

Comment: You have to create oAuth provider on Heroku and provide that link in google action console. So whenever user add device in Google Assistant it will prompt to your oAuth and gives token to google assistant so all the further communication betwen Google Assistant and Heroku Server will be done through that token.

Comment: is it needed to add my device in IFTTT action?

Comment: No if you go for oauth then no IFTTT action will require